# Origin of "cracked the sh**s"

Tags: slang, dialects, australian-english

I heard someone use the expression "he cracked the shits" today which is universally recognised (at least in Australia) to mean "lost his temper".

It struck me that it is a strange expression and the origin is not obvious. It is often used in a context where a threshold of frustration has been reached and the person "cracks it" or loses control and responds angrily, so this may be part of it. Perhaps "the shits" is just tacked on as an intensifier.

I'm pretty sure I've only heard it in the context of Australian English. Is this expression known and used outside Australia, and does anyone have a better explanation of how it might have arisen?

Comment: +1 OK, this can find a place on ELU's archives of useful references. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think this phrase is predominantly restricted to Australia, but with some use [found in New Zealand](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3a.nz%20%22crack%20the%20shits%22). I've never heard it in British or American English, and wouldn't have understood it without suitable context.

### Early use

The earliest example I found in Usenet is from [1994 in rec.motorcycles.dirt](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rec.motorcycles.dirt/bqormG4NBW4) by someone in Melbourne, Australia:

> The conrod, piston, bearings etc etc I ordered finally arrived in the
>   hotel a couple of days after I checked out. The hotel let it sit there for
>   another few days before they let me know. I **cracked the shits** over the
>   phone and the hotel fell for it. They've paid for express delivery to Aus.
>   He he he he he....
>
> I was nearly in *DEEP* shit when I got home. Dumb me left that photo in my
>   suit case. Wife wanted to know whose tits they were.

I found nothing earlier in Google Books or newspaper searches.

### Possible derivation

My guess is the phrase is a combination of *crack* meaning to "open up" and *the shit* meaning "trouble". For example, from [AllDownUnder.com](http://alldownunder.com/australian-slang/dictionary-phrase.htm)'s list of Australian slang phrases:

> **Crack a tinnie**
>   *Meaning*: open a can of cold beer
>   *Example*: Come over to my place and we'll crack a tinnie.

And if someone is "in the shit", they're in (serious) trouble, as shown in the Usenet quote above and defined in this [dictionary of Australian slang](http://www.australiatravelsearch.com.au/trc/slang.html):

> **In the shit** - in serious trouble.

And in *[A Concise Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.fi/books?id=tvRp1whVFUsC&pg=PA326&lpg=PA326&dq=australian%20slang%20%22in%20the%20shit%22&source=bl&ots=gR8T3YVD4D&sig=eigdUO_GgjJ5GpkwWh_nZMe1QIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iPB8UcHpNciD4gTC9oDgCg&ved=0COYBEOgBMBg#v=onepage&q=%22in%20the%20shit%22&f=false)* (Eric Partridge/Paul Beale):

> 12. In *in the shit*, in trouble: low coll.: since mid-C.19. Often *land* (another) *in the shit*, or *fall in the shit* (oneself): since ca. 1879. Cf. the envious (e.g. *he*) *could fall in the shit and come out smelling of violets (roses,* etc.) 13. Hence, among soldiers in WW1, *in the shit* = in the mud and filth in mud and danger; in great and constant danger. [P.B.: E.P. was one of those soldiers, and no doubt wrote this entry with feeling.]

So *crack the shits* could be derived from losing one's temper and putting other people in deep trouble.

Comment: "Crack a sad" and "chuck a sad" mean the same thing as "crack the shits", perhaps they're related.

Comment: Good answer @hugo, but my feeling is that the "crack" in "crack a tinnie" is an unrelated usage. My (completely unsourced) intuition is that it is onomatopoeic: the satisfying "crack!" as you pop the top of a beer can. There are, however, other usages in some of the comments that I didn't think of which are closer to the sense we are looking for- your "Crack a sad" being a good example.

Comment: The "in the shit" in terms of "in trouble" doesn't quite seem to fit either. It feels to me to be more related to something like "I was shitty (upset,angry) about it"

Comment: I like the answer @hugo - the "crack a tinnie" idea also forms a nice analogy with "open up a can of whoop-ass". That doesn't make this derivation true, of course, but it's nice all the same :)

Comment: @tinyd As I mentioned "Cracking a tinnie" has none of the sense of anger that is implicit in "crack the shits" so it a different case altogether. It's usage is no more than to "open" a can, albeit with some enthusiasm given that a tinnie is invariably beer :-)

Comment: I had a discussion with some aussies the other day and they think the phrase is more pom and is not exclusive to Australia. e.g. it is used in Leicester

Answer (score 3):

It is a variation of "get the shits", which means to [to become angry, upset or short tempered](http://www.australiatravelsearch.com.au/trc/slang.html) (as well as the more literal meaning of getting diarrhea). Related phrases are to "get shitty" or to "be shitty", including getting shitty with someone or at someone.

While "get the shits" implies a level of sulking, to "crack the shits" is taken to mean a sudden attack of anger. Other Australian slang phrases use chucking or cracking (often interchangeably) to mean a sudden movement or change of mood, such as chucking or cracking a u-ey (a sudden u-turn while driving), chucking a wobbly or cracking a fat.

Comment: I think you're right, it's definitely related to the sudden, explosive response so this a good answer. Between this answer and @Hugo's I think we may have pinned it down. Not sure if we can mark the question answered though given we don't have any specific historical citations, but I think we have described the correct Australian usage for any interested googlers.

Comment: Is it also equivalent to 'lose the shit'?

Comment: @AnthonyKong yes, but it would be 'lose my shit'

Answer (score 0):

I remember a saying before "cracked a shit" being "got the shits on" or " had the shits on", both meanind angry, frustrated, sulking, upset; contemporary lingo "spat the dummy". Loved that aussie lingo from the seventies. Anyone remember "don't chuck a wet"?

Comment: Are the examples you cite all from the 1970s? Could you please add some detail about the time periods you have in mind?

Comment: I've never heard of "chuck a wet" and I grew up in the seventies in Melbourne. Perhaps it is a regional usage?

Answer (score 0):

"To get the shits on" is most likely an abridged version of "shit on the liver", which comes from an Australian folk song ca. 1935 (Cane Cutter's Lament: http://folkstream.com/020.html). In that song, it is used to describe someone in a bad mood (https://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195563160.001.0001/acref-9780195563160-e-2738)

In subsequent years (ca. 1960's) "shit on the liver" was widely abbreviated to S.O.L. (https://www.macquariedictionary.com.au/resources/aus/word/map/search/word/S.O.L./The%20Riverina/) however, has more recently been replaced by "to get the shits on" and then a subsequent variant of "to crack the shits".

Comment: Interesting. My grandmother who came to Australia used to speak of "having a shitty liver" meaning "in a bad mood". She wasn't one for picking up Australian colloquialisms so I had always assumed that was British slang.